# How to make sure different C++ code base using the same macro?

Tags: c++, macros

We are working on two `C++` code base, let's call it **A** and **B**, the **A** is an build as an library, and distribute the header files `.h` and `.a` file to **B**.

Let's say there is `Lock.h` file in **A** as following:

```
// Lock.h in code base A
class Lock {
    ... ...
#ifdef TRACK_THREAD_OWNER_FOR_DEBUG
    virtual int GetLockOwner();
#endif
    ... ...
private:
    CriticalSection section;
#ifdef TRACK_THREAD_OWNER_FOR_DEBUG
    int threadOwner;
#endif
};

// Caller.cc in code base B
#include "xxx/xxx/Lock.h"
Lock lockObject;
lockObject.Lock();
```

In code base **A**, we by default will enable `TRACK_THREAD_OWNER_FOR_DEBUG` and may change it just before final release day.

We hit some hard bug because `TRACK_THREAD_OWNER_FOR_DEBUG` are different in **A** and **B**, and cause memory corruption because the `sizeof(Lock)` is different in two library.

So how to protect from this error? Can we trigger an compiler error when build the `caller.cc` file if the build macro `TRACK_THREAD_OWNER_FOR_DEBUG` is different in two project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to make this into compiler error, however it should be possible to make this into reasonably clear linker error by exporting some symbol which name depends on the currently defined macros. For example using static guard variable:

```
//  Foo.hpp - library header file
#pragma once

class Foo
{
    public: Foo();
#ifdef IMPORTANT_CONDITION
    int m_field;
#endif
};

class ConditionGuard
{
    public:
    ConditionGuard(void) noexcept
    {
    #ifdef IMPORTANT_CONDITION
        CONDITION_ON();
    #else
        CONDITION_OFF();
    #endif
    }

#ifdef IMPORTANT_CONDITION
    private: static void CONDITION_ON(void);
#else
    private: static void CONDITION_OFF(void);
#endif
};

static ConditionGuard const condition_guard{};

// Foo.cpp - library implementation file 
#include "Foo.hpp"

Foo::Foo(void) {}

#ifdef IMPORTANT_CONDITION
void ConditionGuard::CONDITION_ON(void) {}
#else
void ConditionGuard::CONDITION_OFF(void) {}
#endif
```

Now when user code includes library header `Foo.hpp` it will also trigger construction of `condition_guard` static variable which will call a library function depending on condition being protected. So if there is a translation unit including `Foo.hpp` where `IMPORTANT_CONDITION` is defined differently than in compiled library then there will be a linker error for missing `CONDITION_ON` or `CONDITION_OFF`. `CONDITION_ON` and `CONDITION_OFF` function names should contain error text.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just include the full code for A into project B. What are you trying to do by compiling A into a static library?

I think you're best option is to generate different .a files depending the target. i.e. libA_debug.a when TRACK_THREAD_OWNER_FOR_DEBUG is set, libA.a when it is not.

Then you could set the library to link B to based on whether you are compiling a debug or release version.